# TFS (2013.4) API - DeniedOrNotExistException only on new Areas

Tags: exception, tfs-sdk

I have been using the TFS API (2013.4) successfully to pull data from our in-house Project Support system, and periodically update TFS. There is a minor bug that is making me crazy; I could just ignore it, I suppose... it's not breaking the operation, and after four attempts, it actually saves.

Recently, I created some new Areas (after deleting and/or renaming some other Areas). One of my custom WITs (called a "Risk") is based on the Scrum template's `Bug` WIT.

However, when I change the Area Path of a new "Risk" WIT, it throws a `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DeniedOrNotExistException`. The error message states: `TF26006: Team Foundation could not find 65`

Here's the funny part:

1) ID #65 is the valid ID number for the intended Area. The fact that it actually inferred the correct Area ID tells me that it **was** indeed found!

2) There are no linked references or parent work items that could cause this message (which is normally the reason).

3) When I try to assign and save it to one of my older Areas, there is **no error whatsoever**.

4) I have inspected the TFS Server Database and confirmed that everything looks correct in the `xxTree` table. Deleted Areas have the `InDeletedTree` flag set to 1.

5) I even created a new Area Path with a new name never used before. This gave me only one `DeniedOrNotExistException` instead of four, before the save was accepted.

6) I always call Validate() before a Save(), and it passes every time.

7) I have Admin rights to everything, so security is not the issue.

Could someone explain to me what else could cause this exception. Clearly there is a lot more to it than just checking whether the parent matches the child's Area...

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have just come across this problem in my own application..

Comment: No, I'm afraid. I think eventually I just gave up and recreated the work item.It usually has something to do with parent or child linked items, for what it's worth.

Comment: Damn, I'm seeing the same behaviour while *creating* a work item so doesn't look like that will work for me.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error, running on TFS 2017.  The problem is intermittent.  Could not find anyone else mentioning this issue other than right here....